# Is it acceptable to add a scalar potential to the Lagrangian of a relativistic massive point particle?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, point-particles

Starting from

$$
L=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial t }} \tag{1}
$$

One can rewrite it as $L\to L^2/2$

$$
\frac{L^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial t }.\tag{2}
$$

I am investigating the consequences of adding a scalar potential $U$ as follows:

$$
L_U=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial t}}-U.\tag{3}
$$

Rewriting $L_U\to L_U^2/2$

$$
\frac{L_U^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial t}-\underbrace{U\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial t}} }_{\text{physical interpretation?}}+ \frac{1}{2}U^2.\tag{4}
$$

As we see, the arc length (the square root) remains 'coupled' to $U$. I was not able to find a discussion of such or even similar Lagrangian in the literature. I am trying to find a physical interpretation for the additional terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's square root Lagrangian (3) makes sense. Generically, one is *not* allowed to replace a Lagrangian with its square (or square root), cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506272/11127) Math.SE post. This only works for OP's Lagrangian in the free case where the potential $U=0$ vanishes.

Comment: Why not adding the potential *inside* the square-root?